# Unexpected end of input

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет. Есть такой код:

```
var getChat = setInterval(function(){
    $.post("/chat.php?case=GetAll", function(data){
        if(data != "Error!"){
            var data = $.parseJSON(data);

            $("#messages").html('');
            for(var i in data){
                $("#messages").append('bla bla bla')
            }
        }else{
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    $("#messages").scrollTop($("#messages").get(0).scrollHeight);
}, 2000);
```

И вот он собственно после нескольких итераций (порядка 10-15) выбрасывает сабж, строку указывает

```
var data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

После этого чат перестает обновляться. Тестирую на локалке, поэтому проблема явно не в блокировке ip на сервере

Скрипт отдает 10-20 элементов массива

Такой бред только в Chrome пока замечен. Лечится закрытием вкладки и открытием новой

Comment: `$("#chatbody #messages")` — [ Element identifiers: the id and class attributes][1]

[1]: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: согласен, говнокод, однако на проблему никак не влияет

Comment: Тяжело так ответить, посмотрите в хроме на какую строчку ссылается ошибка, ну и ответ от сервера во вкладке Network

Comment: от сервера возвращается 200 Ok строчку указал

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У вас data — пустая

```
JSON.parse(''); // SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Добавьте проверку:

```
data = data != "" ? $.parseJSON(data) : {};
```

Comment: она не может быть пустой. от сервера 100% что-то возвращается

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bnb8h/1/ — попробуйте так и покажите, что выводит коносль при ошибке

Comment: проблема решилась банальным изменением $.post на $.ajax с нужными параметрами. бред какой-то, однако все равно спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Я тут обнаружил решение проблемы, что мой код ожидал ответ с сервера, а сервак после отправки - молчал. Вот и выпадала ошибки что ожиданное окончание жсона

```
fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(json),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
        .then(res => res.json())// вот тут мой код и ожидает ответ из сервака
        .then((res) => {
          toastr.success('Created Type is sent successfully');
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Type send failed', err);
          toastr.warning('Type send failed');
        })
```