# php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); где нужно разместить

Tags: php

Где в пхп файле разместить эту команду?

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

нужно к пхп обратиться через $.post

Comment: До первого echo или другого вывода, обычно в начале скрипта

Comment: Вы к своему php скрипту хотите отправить post запрос?

Comment: скрипт находится на моем сервере и это мой скрипт

Answer (score 6, accepted):

До первого вывода контента. А где именно зависит от вашей архитектуры, фреймворка и т.п.

Еще можно использовать проверку:

```
if (!headers_sent()) {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
} else {
    // обработка ошибки или уведомление разработчикам
}
```

Comment: когда виставляю то видает локальною ошибку `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < index.html:2`

Comment: @МиколаКікець не страдаю телепатией к сожалению... Какую?

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < index.html:2`

Comment: @МиколаКікець ну правильно, это `php` код, который надо вставлять в `php` скрипты. Вы знакомы с [PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/langref.php)?

Comment: Код серверной страницы:

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
  
  <head>

    <meta charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>It works</title>
    
  </head>
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');?>
  <body>
<?php

$data = $_POST["data"];
if($data == "count")
 if (is_int($number)){
    echo json_encode(['status' => 1, 'count' => $number]);
 } else {
  echo json_encode(['status' => 0, 'count' => 0]);
 }
?>
    Hello World!
<a href = "vtnuft/">go next</a>
  </body>
</html>`

Comment: или где именно нужно вставлять?

Comment: @МиколаКікець у вас есть свои Php скрипты на сервере? Вот туда и нужно это писать

Comment: ok я написал туда но выбила ошибка: "end of input"

Comment: В браузере выдал такую ошибку? Ну так это отлично, значит запрос дошел до скрипта. Читайте про новую вашу ошибку – http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/244235/unexpected-end-of-input